# How can I dynamically add a new vue instance from a button click?

Tags: vue.js, dynamic

To give some background, I have a vue instance that is using a vue multi-select component from https://vue-multiselect.js.org/ that renders a list based on the selections chosen.

HTML

```html
<div id="timesheetTopics">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <multiselect
                v-model="value"
                placeholder="Select your topics here"
                :options="options"
                :multiple="true"
                track-by="topic"
                :custom-label="customLabel"
                @select="updateSelected"
                @remove="removeTagAndRelevantTeamMembers">
        </multiselect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <a class="btn btn-info float-right" style="margin-top: -1px;" data-target="#project1"
           data-toggle="collapse">Collapse</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="resources-list">
            <li class="resource-item" id="timesheetListPlaceholder">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    Select topics in the bar to build your list of team members
                </div>
            </li>
            <template v-for="selectedTopicsRelatedTeamMember in selectedTopicsRelatedTeamMembers">
                <template v-for="(related_team_member, index) in selectedTopicsRelatedTeamMember.related_team_members">

                    <li class="resource-item" :data-index="index">
                        <div class="col-xs-2" :id="index">
                            <span class="badge badge-topics-large">[[ related_team_member.topic ]]</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <a><b>[[ related_team_member.name ]]</b></a>
                            <span>[[ related_team_member.email ]]</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <b>Started:</b>
                            <span class="badge badge-date"> [[ related_team_member.first_activity ]]</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <b>Time Spent:</b>
                            <span class="badge badge-date"> [[ related_team_member.time_spent ]]</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <b>Percentage:</b>
                            <span class="badge badge-percent"> [[ related_team_member.percentage_spent ]]</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="delete-controls" v-on:click.prevent="removeDependency(index)">
                            <i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Vue.js

```js
new Vue({
    components: {
        Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: {
        value: '',
        options: [
            {topic: 'Kashmir', related_team_members: [{name: 'Alex Ackermans', email: 'alex@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '18hours', percentage_spent: '23%', first_activity: '3 months ago', topic: 'Kashmir'}]},
            {topic: 'Blockchain', related_team_members: [{name: 'Seraphin Vandegar', email: 'seraphin.vandegar@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '30hours', percentage_spent: '40%', first_activity: '6 months ago', topic: 'Blockchain'}, {name: 'Jim Halpert', email: 'jim.halpert@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '32hours', percentage_spent: '38%', first_activity: '9 months ago', topic: 'Blockchain'}]},
            {topic: 'Social Reunion Tour', related_team_members: [{name: 'Chris Mok', email: 'chris.mok@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '15hours', percentage_spent: '20%', first_activity: '4 months ago', topic: 'Social Reunion Tour'}]},
            {topic: 'Snapchat', related_team_members: [{name: 'Demo Test', email: 'demo.test@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '8hours', percentage_spent: '9%', first_activity: '1 week ago', topic: 'Snapchat'}, {name: 'Frasca', email: 'frasca@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '4hours', percentage_spent: '5%', first_activity: '2 months ago', topic: 'Snapchat'}]},
            {topic: 'Botsociety', related_team_members: [{name: 'Pam Halpert', email: 'pam.halpert@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '10hours', percentage_spent: '7%', first_activity: '5 months ago', topic: 'Botsociety'}, {name: 'Michael Scott', email: 'Michael.Scott@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '2hours', percentage_spent: '3%', first_activity: '1 months ago', topic: 'Botsociety'}]},
            {topic: 'OpenAI', related_team_members: [{name: 'Dwight Schrute', email: 'dwight.schrute@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '50hours', percentage_spent: '48%', first_activity: '12 months ago', topic: 'OpenAI'}]},
            {topic: 'Tedium', related_team_members: [{name: 'Jarvis Tetch', email: 'jarvis.tetch@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '5hours', percentage_spent: '6%', first_activity: '3 weeks ago', topic: 'Tedium'}]},
            {topic: 'Xmas', related_team_members: [{name: 'Bruce Wayne', email: 'bruce.wayne@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '7hours', percentage_spent: '12%', first_activity: '2 weeks ago', topic: 'Xmas'}, {name: 'Alfred Pennyworth', email: 'alfred.pennyworth@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '3hours', percentage_spent: '4%', first_activity: '1 week ago', topic: 'Xmas'}, {name: 'James Gordon', email: 'james.gordon@anteateranalytics.com', time_spent: '1hour', percentage_spent: '2%', first_activity: '12 hours ago', topic: 'Xmas'}]},
        ],
        selectedTopicsRelatedTeamMembers: [],
    },
    methods: {
        customLabel(option) {
            return `${option.topic}`
        },
        updateSelected(value) {
                this.selectedTopicsRelatedTeamMembers.push(value);
                console.log(this.selectedTopicsRelatedTeamMembers)
                $('#timesheetListPlaceholder').hide();
        },
        removeDependency(index) {
            this.selectedTopicsRelatedTeamMembers.splice(index, 1)
        },
        removeTagAndRelevantTeamMembers: function (value) {
            array = this.selectedTopicsRelatedTeamMembers;
            $.each(array, function(i){
            if(array[i].topic === value.topic) {
                array.splice(i,1);
                return false;
            }
        });
        }
    }
}).$mount('#timesheetTopics');
```

The functionality I'm looking for is the ability to allow a user to press a button and create a new vue instance below the first that has the same components and layout. (see example below)

[image: vue instance w/ button to add new vue instance]

[image: Second vue instance added below first vue instance]

Is there a simple way to be able to get this functionality? Because from what I understand, only vue components can be added dynamically and if I have to convert my instance into components, I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you need an entire new instance rather than just making that into a component and making a new instance of the component?

Comment: No there's no reason I need an entire new instance. I do understand that I could turn it into a component to be added dynamically; although, I don't completely understand on how I would make this conversion. would I have to convert internal elements to separate components added together to create one big component? Or could I convert the whole instance into a single component?

Comment: You can convert the whole thing to a single component if you want using `Vue.component('somename', { ... });` and then reference that component in the template of wherever you mount the vue instance.